# How to flood fill shapes made with line segment tool on Adobe Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, line-art, fill

How do I flood fill like the paint bucket in Microsoft Paint?

I've tried selecting a group of line segments -> object -> live paint -> make. But it changes the weight of the lines to all the same. I want the line weights to remain the same.
[image: Here is the image I am trying to fill]

Also, say I select the left side of the "V" to fill the area inside of the "V", how do I select only the left side of the "V" again to fill the area to the left of the "V"?

I want the image to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this. The trick is to *double click* on the paint bucket tool and a dialog opens. In the dialog specify that the bucket only affects fills only by unchecking the paint strokes option.

[image: options]

**Image 1**: In live paint bucket options disable stroke filling

After doing this it works like you expected.

[image]

**Image 2**: And it works like expected. Even with a slight gap in the join of circle and diagonal thin line.

You can also copy the shape on a second layer and work behind the strokes if you wish to work with shape builder instead.

**PS**: Note that live paint bucket can live with small gaps but you can not adjust the size at least not in my version. But you can in shape builder so if you have bigger gaps then use that instead.